# When should we use <router-outlet></router-outlet>?

Tags: angular, angular5

For routing, we use either route.params.subscribe() or

What is the difference between these two and how to use them together?

Answer (score 4):

This Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills based on the current router state.

### You can try this

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Answer (score 1):

In Angular,  to tell the Angular compiler(broadly) that this is the space where you'll perform html changes on URL changes.

Think of this in jQuery or JavaScript - 
`

```
var a1 = "Content 1";
var b1 = "Content 2";
var router = $("router-outlet");

function route(param) {
    $("router-outlet").html("")
    if (param == 'a') {
        $("router-outlet").html(a1);
    } else {
        $("router-outlet").html(b1)
    }
}
```

`
Now the HTML is like this -

```
<div>
  <span onclick = "route('a')">Post Content A</span>
  <span onclick = "route('b')">Post Content B </span>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Plnkr : http://embed.plnkr.co/iB6kON8mRtgX5CEBili9/

This is the most basic idea of .